# MOD_rewrite from static to dynamic URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

**I have the following URL which is correct...**

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/cask-beer/wells-and-youngs

**but i need it to render this page:**

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/cask-beer?catID=4

This is my current .htaccess which serves other pages correctly already. I want to add something to manage this other rule. I had an attempt where you can cask-beer

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

#
# Setting rewrite rules
#

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # Set next line to your Wolf CMS root - if not in subdir, then just /
  RewriteBase /

  # Rules to allow install sequence to test for mod_rewrite support
  RewriteRule ^install/index.html$ install/index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^install/index.php$ install/index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^install/$ install/index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  # Administration URL rewriting.
  RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ admin/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  # Main URL rewriting.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?WOLFPAGE=$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l  

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cask-beer?$1

</IfModule>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: you need a 1 to 1 rule? I mean, this rule must be valid ONLY for that url or you need to rewrite a group of urls

Comment: mmm there are three categories in total...

cask-beer,
cider,
specialist-beer

each of which are followed by the product,
for example cask-beer/fullers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this rule at the top of your other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^cask-beer/wells-and-youngs$ cask-beer?catID=4 [L,QSA]
```